# "Wi-Fi Direct" libraries for Android?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is anyone aware of [WiFi Direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct) (a WiFi peer-to-peer variant) libraries or SDKs for Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wi-Fi Direct API is availible since [API 14](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html)

The package is called [android.net.wifi.p2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Currently any [peer-to-peer networking is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5318457/83446) in Android but hopefully [support for WiFi Direct](http://mobilesociety.typepad.com/mobile_life/2011/03/wi-fi-direct-coming-to-an-android-phone-near-you.html) will be coming soon. As a result however there are no SDK's or API's available.

Comment: Peer-to-peer networking is possible. It is ad-hoc networking that is disabled. Wi-Fi Direct is peer-to-peer, but not ad-hoc. It uses the 802.11 infrastructure mode. There is a feature request that has been pending forever to implement 802.11 ad-hoc mode, which would enable people to talk between devices with no soft AP.