# Sharing files using WiFi between android devices

Tags: android

How to enable WiFi and to make list of the devices found after searching for wifi connectivity in android phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices could not originally do this without an access point in between, except by rooting and directly manipulating the network settings to permit ad-hoc wireless. However a few newer devices seem to support it.

[Android Wifi direct multiple connection ad-hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318457/android-wifi-direct-multiple-connection-ad-hoc)
*(Arguably this could be closed as a duplicate of that, but I thought there was room for more explanation than found there.  There was another recent question too, but I can't find it)*

If one device supports wifi tethering that can be enabled and the other connect to it, but then all network traffic from the other device would go through it, potentially using up the data plan (ie, okay for two devices with the same owner, not a good idea for casual transfers)

The "standard" solution would still be to use a wifi access point, and potentially to do the transfer via an Internet server as intermediary, which has the side benefit of not needing the devices to be on the same network.